# How can I open the Dropbox preferences window using Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, dropbox

How can I open the Dropbox preferences window using Applescript?

I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Dropbox"
        keystroke "," using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

But this isn't working. Perhaps it's because Dropbox is running in the tray / background? ie: I can't switch to it using command-tab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.  NSStatusItems (of which Dropbox is one) are not visible via accessibility.  [This weblog entry](http://carpeaqua.com/2010/01/24/nsstatusitem-not-supported-by-voiceover/) and [this bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/6832098) provide more information.  Please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and reference that bug number if this is important to you.

Comment: `NSStatusItems` might be accessible using ApplescriptObjC in Xcode.

Comment: @NR - This looks to be unfortunately true, at least as of the current date. :(